# How to convert postgresql column into a float for a scoped search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to search my postgresql db in rails. I followed the [Railscasts #111 Advanced Search](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised) tutorial and it is working for the name and category of my items column in plain text. However, I want to set a min/max price on my search as well which is where I come into my problem. In my db my price is stored as a string in the format "AU $49.95". Can I convert this into a float on the fly in my scoped search? If so how? If not, what should I do?

Here is the code:

search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :keywords, :catagory, :minimum_price, :maximum_price

    def items
      @items ||= find_items
    end

    private

    def find_items
      scope = Item.scoped({})
      scope = scope.scoped :conditions => ["to_tsvector('english', items.name) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", "%#{keywords}%"] unless keywords.blank?
      scope = scope.scoped :conditions => ["items.price >= ?", "AU \$#{minimum_price.to_s}"] unless minimum_price.blank?
      # scope = scope.scoped :conditions => ["items.price <= ?", "AU \$#{maximum_price.to_s}"] unless maximum_price.blank?
      scope = scope.scoped :conditions => ["to_tsvector('english', items.catagory) @@ ?", catagory] unless catagory.blank?
      scope
    end

end
```

searches_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    if @search.save
      redirect_to @search, :notice => "Successfully created search."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Thanks for reading this far!

Comment: You'd better not store numbers as string. Even if you find a workaround, it will be a performance hit to convert a large amount of data to float.

Comment: ok thanks. Maybe the best course of action is to change the db. I was being lazy when I was storing it. It has come back to bite me now

Comment: Woah, [you'd better not store them as floats in the database!](http://everything2.com/title/never+store+currency+in+a+float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the data type [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) or [`money`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-money.html) for exact numerical calculation without rounding errors - and sorting as a number (not as text).
Converting string literal to `numeric` should not be a performance problem at all.